# Datatables aoColumns and bAutoWidth not working?

Tags: datatables

This javascript

```js
$('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "width": "50%" },
            { "width": "100px" },
            { "width": "100px" },
            { "width": "50px" },
            { "width": "100px" }
        ]});
```

Together with this table

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="" id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Rendering engine</th>
    <th>Browser</th>
    <th>Platform(s)</th>
    <th>Engine version</th>
    <th>CSS grade</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Trident</td>
    <td>Internet
        Explorer 4.0</td>
    <td>Win 95+</td>
    <td> 4</td>
    <td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Trident</td>
    <td>Internet
        Explorer 5.0</td>
    <td>Win 95+</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Trident</td>
    <td>Internet
        Explorer 5.5</td>
    <td>Win 95+</td>
    <td>5.5</td>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Trident</td>
    <td>Internet
        Explorer 6</td>
    <td>Win 98+</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Trident</td>
    <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
    <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Ends up being not a fixed size table.

First of all, I don't want it to be 100% width, and secondly, putting px or % in the js part, has no effect at all.

Am I overlooking something?

[See here in this fiddle about the datatables auto column width problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1852/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would strongly recommend that you upgrade to 1.10.x -> **http://www.datatables.net/download/**  or at least the latest version of the 1.9-series, [**1.9.4**](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/).

Then, yes - when using 1.9.0 as you are, (all 1.9.x versions) the columns `width` option is named [**sWidth**](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#sWidth). So instead :

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   "bAutoWidth": false,
   "aoColumns": [
      { "sWidth": "50%" },
      { "sWidth": "100px" },
      { "sWidth": "100px" },
      { "sWidth": "50px" },
      { "sWidth": "100px" }
   ]
});
```

To deal with your requirement "*I don't want it to be 100% width*" you must specify a width for the table, or at least a `max-width`. Otherwise datatables will assume the table should be 100% in width, and therefore expand the `"sWidth": "50%"` column to whatever there is left. So if you want the table to be 700px, as an example :

```css
#example {
    width: 700px;
}
```

your fiddle forked -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9n5vrbnz/**

If you want a *completely* fixed width, that is, the table and the injected controls like the search box and pagination to be kept within a certain width, you can style the wrapper element. It is always named `<table id>_wrapper` :

```css
#example_wrapper {
    width: 700px;
}
```

se fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1rce0d4k/**

Comment: @Toskan, yes off course this was a hack. Today there is dataTables 1.10.x, which provides an API so those hacks not is nessecary anymore - http://www.datatables.net/